# my reset button for a contact form isnt resetting

Tags: html, forms, button, input, reset

I used code from a website to create a form but the reset button that I added doesn't work with it! I've tried changing it to a simple input type but when I press the reset button, nothing happens. I've also tried getting rid of the form-group divs but the same problem occurs. I know the style part is pretty complex but that is what the example of the contact form had and I am really happy with how it looks aesthetically. for my assignment, I do not need the submit button to work, only the reset button. here is the code and the style sheet:

```
#form {
  display:block;
}
.contact-form {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: -apple-system, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 1.10rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #FFFAFA;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #CC7722;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border: 5px solid #697645;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1 rem;
}
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #3D2407;
  background-color: #FFFAFA;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 3px solid #697645;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.form-control:focus {
  border: 3px solid #8A9A5B;
}
select.form-control[size], select.form-control[multiple] {
  height: auto;
}
textarea.form-control {
  font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
  height: auto;
}
label.label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3D2407;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .btn {
    transition: none;
  }
}
.btn:hover {
  color: #212529;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.btn:focus, .btn.focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #697645;
}
.btn-primary {
  color:#FFFAFA;
  background-color: #697645;
  border-color: #697645;
}
.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background-color: #8A9A5B;
  border-color: #8A9A5B;
}
.btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary.focus {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background-color: #8A9A5B;
  border-color: #8A9A5B;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #697645;
}
.btn-lg, .btn-group-lg>.btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}
.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.btn-block+.btn-block {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
input[type="submit"].btn-block, input[type="reset"].btn-block,
input[type="button"].btn-block {
  width: 100%;
}




<div id="form"
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname" class="label">First name:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" class="form-control" required>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lname" class="label">Last name:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="last name" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message" class="label">Answer:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="6" maxlength="3000" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
<br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="reset" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an input instead of a button to reset the contents of the form. It works like that:

```
<input type="reset" value="[your button label here]">
```

Further, you should insert a `>` after the id attribute of the div with the id `form`. (The line directly after your css):

```
<div id="form">
```

After that, it should work.